# Where are external Gradle dependencies stored?

Tags: gradle

I'm using Gradle and I gave the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.2.2'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:3.8.2'
}
```

I want to download the driver of MongoDB. I typed:

> gradle build

and after a few seconds I got a message saying the the build had succeeded. Now, I'm looking for the jar file/directory of MongoDB driver, and I don't find it. Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<GRADLE_USER_HOME>/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.2.2/<checksum of the JAR>/mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar
```