# Gradle: Can't resolve a variable that has to be included in external dependency

Tags: gradle

This question follows this post: [Gradle: Where are external dependencies stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189093/gradle-where-are-external-dependencies-stored/41189798?noredirect=1#comment69581145_41189798).

I want to use MongoDB driver for Java, so I added the following line:

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.0'
```

to build.gradle file. After finishing the build successfully, I found the jar file of the dependency in ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb.

I also added the path ~/.gradle to external libraries.

[image]

However, when I write the statement

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
```

inside my project, I get an error:

> "Can't resolve symbol 'mongodb'".

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Now IJ searches in `.gradle` for classfiles. Of course mongodb is not found in there. As I said in the comment of the other issue, if you change the dependencies in your Gradle file and did not enable auto-import when you imported the Gradle project into IJ, its library configuration will not automatically update. Either tell IJ manually to refresh the library configuration from the Gradle file or activate auto-import so that it automatically sees when you change the Gradle file and automatically updates the library configuration.

Comment: I activated auto-import by file->settings->editor->general->Auto Import -> Insert imports in paste: ALL. 
It still didn't resolve it.

Comment: Not if you don't ask what you did not understand. Either open the Gradle tool window and use the refresh button, or go to settings and enable auto-import, I don't know how to be more specific without a question

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you opened the project as Gradle project
2. When you add dependency, press on the sync dependencies button