# Gradle: How can I get the path to a specific external dependency stored in .gradle?

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator

I'm quite new to gradle. For the [OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) repo, I've taken advantage of the very convenient gradle plugin to do almost exactly what I want (generate HTML2 static docs on my openapi.json spec), except that there's an old-time bug where that doc isn't populated correctly. There was a PR request that hasn't been touched for many months that mostly fixes the issue, so I built a custom jar with the changes.

I want to create a new gradle task that runs this custom external jar as an executable, so that I can essentially do the same functionality as their grade plugin. By doing so I've added it to a maven repository and pulled it down as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-custom-cli:3.0.0'
}
```

This then pulls the jar into my External Libraries directory which is stored in a very specific location in the cache (ref: [Gradle: Where are external dependencies stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189093/gradle-where-are-external-dependencies-stored))

How can I get the exact location of this jar? Is there any other approach that would seem more best practice?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're taking a much harder route to get custom documentation in place. If the issue you've found is with a template only, you can specify `templateDir` in your Gradle task and point to a directory holding your custom directory.

For example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:4.2.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'

task buildGoSdk(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask){
    generatorName = "go"
    templateDir = "$rootDir/custom-templates".toString()
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/petstore-v3.0.yaml".toString()
    additionalProperties = [
            packageName: "petstore"
    ]
    outputDir = "$buildDir/go".toString()
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "threetenp"
    ]
}
```

Then, you can build this with `gradle buildGoSdk`.

If the issue you're looking to fix has some logic in the Java code that manages the generator, you can create a [custom generator jar](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization) and load this without modifying the gradle plugin itself.

I actually have a sample repo for the HTML2 generator which does exactly this. My example only changes the generator name and adds Google Analytics as a config option and to the template, but it should be easy enough to follow along. See https://github.com/jimschubert/custom-generator-example

The key part would be to add your custom generator jar to the buildscript dependencies like this (taken from my repo example):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "us.jimschubert.examples:html-generator:1.0-SNAPSHOT"
        classpath "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:3.3.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'

task buildCustomHtml2(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask){
    generatorName = "custom-html2"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/petstore-v3.0.yaml".toString()
    additionalProperties = [
            appName: "My Custom HTML2 Generator",
            googleAnalytics: "12345-6"
    ]
    outputDir = "$buildDir/custom-html".toString()
}
```